# Flex navigator.pushView slow

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, flex4.5

This is a general question on optimization technique and please I am more than willing to rewrite a majority of my code as I am moving a lot of it to a library.

My concern applies not so much to flex performance as I have used methods that have reduced cpu/memory footprint so performance is quick when inside a view.

The problem I have is with the navigator.pushView which seems slow, I do call my init function on creationComplete for the view but I have it factored so my init looks like:

```
private function init() : void {
  doStuff1();
  doStuff2();
  doStuff3();
}
```

What can I do to make the view transition smooth? This is on a mobile device.

I have considered delaying off all of the code inside the init function using a timer so that for lets say the first 3 seconds there is nothing happening and the view has all the frames it needs but that doesn't seem right.

Advice would be much appreciated!

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance really depends on what you're doing in those "doStuff()" methods.  A few things to consider:

1) At the time creationComplete() executes; the view has already rendered once.  Are you doing anything that will cause the thing to render itself again?   Changing styles, and many properties on children components will cause that child to re-render and often the view component.

A lot of people use creationComplete as a constructor when, in reality, that is the worst place to put "constructor style" code.  Instead you should consider using preinitialize for most stuff, or initialize if you need to set properties on children components.

2) [viewActivate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#event%3aviewActivate) executes after the transition occurs.  So, perhaps you should consider moving code out of creationComplete and into viewActivate.  More info on a [mobile view's lifecycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html#WSe11993ea1bd776e5-5a47080c12a43a582b9-8000) is here.

Comment: viewActivate may be it! I'll try it - thank you for the info - really quite appreciated!

Comment: I also had a nesting problem! Lots of nested groups (skinnable containers/vgroup, hgroup etc).

Comment: For performance I recommend you use as few containers as possible.  For every group you use; that is another layout algorithm you have to run.

Comment: I thought that viewActivate will execute after the transition, but if I debug the application It doesn't happen. The function called by viewActivate event is called before the view is changed. Is it only in the debugger?